# Linq Aggregate gives null value rather than expected return List

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

I'm attempting to utilize linq aggregate in order to mimic a reduce behavior. I need `GroupingMethod` to return a List of arrays.For some reason `GroupingMethod` returns null no matter what. I appreciate any help.

```
List<Group> groupings = GroupingMethod(new int[] {9,6,9,3,5,3,6,6,3,5,5,1,6,9,8});

static List<Group> GroupingMethod(int[] ValueList)
    {
        int groupTotal = 0;
        Group newGroup = new Group();
        var put = ValueList.Aggregate(new List<Group>(), (acc, x) =>
        {
            List<Group> polp = acc;
            groupTotal = groupTotal + x;
            if (groupTotal < 10)
            {
                newGroup.AddInt(x);
            } else
            {
                polp.Add(newGroup);
                newGroup.Clear();
                groupTotal = 0;
            }
            return polp;
        });
        return put;
    }


class Group
{
    List<int> iGrouping = new List<int>();
    public Group(int AddInt)
    {
        iGrouping.Add(AddInt);
    }
    public Group()
{

}
    public void AddInt(int IntToAdd)
    {
        iGrouping.Add(IntToAdd);
    }
    public void Clear()
    {
        iGrouping.Clear();
    }
public int CombinedGroupValue { get{return iGrouping.Sum();}}          
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the end of your `GroupingMethod`, which makes it really hard to help. (You get as far as declaring the `put` variable, but we don't see anything that returns from `GroupingMethod`.) Please provide a [mcve], formatted how you'd want to see the code yourself, so that you put us in the best position possible to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet I corrected it, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the ```GroupingMethod``` returns null? Or returns empty list?

Comment: I've just tried the code you posted, and it doesn't return null. It returns a list with 6 elements. Again, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It also helps if your question actually says what you mean - instead of a `List` of arrays, I assume you want a `List<T>` of `Group` since that is what your code says. Also, LINQ isn't useful for every problem, nor is it faster, if your `Aggregate` body is that large, you should just use `for` or `foreach`.

Comment: Also, your code has a design flaw - you add `newGroup` to `polp` but then you call `newGroup.Clear()` which erases the group you just added, so you end up with `put` containing multiple copies of the same `Group`, all of which are empty. You also don't put the `x` that goes over 10 into `newGroup` after calling `Clear`, did you mean to just throw it away? Can you show the result you expect to get???